# Updation not working using pdo in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update the records but the update query is not working for some reason.It is deleting and inserting fine but somehow the update doesn't work.I have checked various questions but couldn't find the answer.I have checked the data inserted in the query and its fine too.This is my code.

```
  <?php   
    require 'database.php';
        $ido = 0;
         if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
              $ido = $_REQUEST['id'];
              echo $ido;
         }
    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track validation errors
        $nameError = null;
        $descError = null;
        $priceError = null;
        // keep track post values
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $desc = $_POST['desc'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        // validate input
        $valid = true;
        if (empty($name)) {
            $nameError = 'Please enter Name';
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (empty($desc)) {
            $descError = 'Please enter Valid descriptin';
            $valid = false;
        }
        if (empty($price) || filter_var($price, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) == false) {
            $priceError = 'Please enter a valid price';
            $valid = false;
        }  

        // insert data
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE Items SET I_name = ? , I_desc = ? ,I_price = ? WHERE I_id = ?"; <---This is the update query part
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($name,$desc,$price,$ido));    <---these are the values inserted
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
      }
        else {
        echo $ido;
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Items where I_id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($ido));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $name = $data['I_name'];
        $desc = $data['I_desc'];
        $price = $data['I_price'];
        Database::disconnect();
    }

   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

     <body>
     <div class="container">

                <div class="span10 offset1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Update Items</h3>
                    </div>

                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="update_items.php" method="post">
                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($nameError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="name" type="text"  placeholder="Item Name" value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($nameError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $nameError;?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($descError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="desc" type="text" placeholder="Item Description" value="<?php echo !empty($desc)?$desc:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($descError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $descError;?></span>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($priceError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Price</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="price" type="text" placeholder="Item Price" value="<? php echo !empty($price)?$price:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($priceError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $priceError;?></span>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-actions">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                          <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="update_items.php" method="post">
                                                      ^ nothing here
```

As you can see you are posting and there is no query variable after the url you are posting to.

Then you check for the ID:

```
$ido = 0;
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $ido = $_REQUEST['id'];
    echo $ido;
}
```

`$ido` will remain `0` as there is no `$_GET['id']`.

You can either modify your form to add the ID or add a hidden variable in the form with the ID and check for `$_POST['id']`.

I'd go for the second option:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="update_items.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $ido; ?>">
```

and in php:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
   $ido = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: I am actually getting the $_GET['id'] from another page and it definitely has value.I have echoed it just to make sure.

Comment: @soldiershin It might when you load the form, but not when you post it, check the first line of my answer.